# Android: Using padding or margins to adjust a view anchored via toLeftOf/toRightOf

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two imageviews I am trying to position on the screen in a RelativeLayout. However, one of the images' left edge juts out to the left in one section, while the rest is just a straight line. I want the other image to align with the straight part of the line, NOT the extra part which sticks out.

And no, I can't edit the image resources, I won't get into all the details, I'll just say I need all of the pieces the way they are.

Here is a really ugly image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/block"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/interior"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/open_wall"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/block" />
```

But it didn't work (tried paddingRight) as well. I think because the the view is anchoring itself to the immediate left of the open_wall image, it won't allow you to move past that dividing line, if you will.

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do to get what I'm after?

EDIT: Upon request, the images I'm trying to work with:

[image: red] (the red in my diagram)

[image: black] (the black in my diagram)

Comment: can you post the image resources? I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dip"
        android:src="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="28dip"
        android:src="@drawable/black" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The only thing you have to do is play a little with the two `dip` values because I do not have the resources at the same resolution as you do.

This is how it looks like:

[image]